# AWK: confirming matching columns of consecutive rows

Tags: linux, awk, compare

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this question.  For the last day I have been trying to solve a problem and haven’t come any closer to a solution.  I have a sample file of data that contains the following:

```
Fighter@Trainer
Bobby@SamBonen
Billy@BobBrown
Sammy@DJacobson
James@DJacobson
Donny@SonnyG
Ben@JasonS
Dave@JuanO
Derrek@KMcLaughlin
Dillon@LGarmati
Orson@LGarmati
Jeff@RodgerU
Brad@VCastillo
```

The goal is to identify “Trainers” that have have more then one fighter.  My gut feeling is the “getline” and variable declaration directives in AWK are going to be needed.  I have tried different combinations of

```
awk -F@ 'NR>1{a=$2; getline; if($2 = a) {print $0,"Yes"} else {print $0,"NO"}}' sample.txt
```

Yet, the output is nowhere near the desired results.  In fact, it doesn’t even output all the rows in the sample file!

My desired results are:

```
Fighter@Trainer
Bobby@SamBonen@NO
Billy@BobBrown@NO
Sammy@DJacobson@YES
James@DJacobson@YES
Donny@SonnyG@NO
Ben@JasonS@NO
Dave@JuanO@NO
Derrek@KMcLaughlin@NO
Dillon@LGarmati@YES
Orson@LGarmati@YES
Jeff@RodgerU@NO
Brad@VCastillo@NO
```

I am completely lost as to where to go from here.  I have been searching and trying to find a solution to no avail, and I'm looking for some input.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `getline`.
You could just process the input normally,
building up counts per trainer,
and print the result in an `END` block:

```
awk -F@ '{
  lines[NR] = $0;
  trainers[NR] = $2;
  counts[$2]++;
}
END {
  print lines[1];
  for (i = 2; i <= length(lines); i++) {
    print lines[i] "@" (counts[trainers[i]] > 1 ? "YES" : "NO");
  }
}' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make two passes:

```
$ cat p.awk
BEGIN {FS=OFS="@"}
NR==1 {print;next};
NR==FNR {++trainers[$2]; next}
FNR>1 {$3=(trainers[$2]>1)?"YES":"NO"; print}

$ awk -f p.awk p.txt p.txt
Fighter@Trainer
Bobby@SamBonen@NO
Billy@BobBrown@NO
Sammy@DJacobson@YES
James@DJacobson@YES
Donny@SonnyG@NO
Ben@JasonS@NO
Dave@JuanO@NO
Derrek@KMcLaughlin@NO
Dillon@LGarmati@YES
Orson@LGarmati@YES
Jeff@RodgerU@NO
Brad@VCastillo@NO
```

**Explained:**

Set the input and output file separators:

```
BEGIN {FS=OFS="@"}
```

Print the header:

```
NR==1 {print;next};
```

First pass, count occurrences of each trainer:

```
NR==FNR {++trainers[$2]; next}
```

Second pass, set YES or NO according to trainer count, and print result:

```
FNR>1 {$3=(trainers[$2]>1)?"YES":"NO"; print}
```